# Data not sending to server on abp.ajax request

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate template.  I am having problems getting the server to receive the data I am sending from an abp.ajax post request (code shown below).

The console is logging the correct data (as shown in screenshot 1) but server is not returning the correct data.  When I debug, the data of id 1000 is appearing as 0 on server even though console logs 1000 and that's the object sent.

Screenshot 1:

[image: Screenshot 1 - Showing console log]

Screenshot 2: 
[image]

The Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.default-customer-selection', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var info = {
            toCustomerId: 1000 //Just trying to keep this simple for now
        };

        console.log(info);

        abp.ajax({
            url: abp.appPath + 'Portal/Catalog/SwitchCustomer',
            data: JSON.stringify(info),
            success: function (data) {
              console.log('Data Returned: ' + data.personId);
            }
        });
    });
```

Model/DTO Input for Switch Customer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MySolution.Catalog.Dtos
{
    public class SwitchCustomerInput
    {
        public long ToCustomerId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller Function:

```
public class CatalogController : MySolutionControllerBase
{ 
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SwitchCustomer(SwitchCustomerInput input)
    {
        return Json(new { PersonId = input.ToCustomerId });
    }
}
```

I am following the guide and other pre-built examples I see in the project that are working properly in the solution already:  https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v1.5.2/Javascript-API/AJAX

Am I missing a step?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`abp.ajax` gets options as an object. You can pass any parameter that is valid in jQuery's $.ajax method. There are some **defaults** here: dataType is '**json**', type is '**POST**' and contentType is '**application/json**' (So, you call JSON.stringify to convert javascript object to JSON string before sending to the server).

You need to add `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter of the action like below :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SwitchCustomer([FromBody]SwitchCustomerInput input)
{
      return Json(new { PersonId = input.ToCustomerId });
}
```